# Listing all the drives with their size in Cocoa (Mac OS X)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

[image: List all the drives with free space ,used and total size]

How to implement the drive list shown in figure in cCcoa and when I click on a specific drive it should open that drive.

Thanks...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @sosborn : I am using [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributeOfFileSystemForPath:path error:nil]; to get sizes but I don't know how to get drive icon,drive lists.

Comment: could you tell me how you listed the discs in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [FileSystemItem.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OutlineView/Listings/FileSystemItem_m.html)

For file icon use

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:fullPath];
```

Comment: But how can i get all disk partitions ?

Comment: NSArray *AllVolumes= [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Volumes" error:nil];

Comment: thanks it works fine for removable media also..I want to calculate the size of all files in a volume and display it using NSBrowser.What is the best way to calculate file size(considering performance).

Comment: if you want only volumes size, you will get it from attributeOfFileSystemForPath.

Comment: But how can i update the size if file size changes(without reloading all files sizes in the column)?

Comment: you can give one option to refresh of you can use file system watcher.